Combine Dropdown Div with a ToolTip
Can't seem to make it happen for some reason. Either .ToolTip just appears ( instead of a gentle dropdown ), or .ToolTipText won't appear and .ToolTip have a weird transition ( Like opening/closing from the middle ) - https://jsfiddle.net/Apryed/40exvq6s/2/ .
I combined them this way:
<h3 class="ShowHide">Text to click and display/hide</h3>
    <div class="ToolTip">
        <div class="ToolTipText">Descriptive Text</div>
        <div>
            <label for="date">SaveDate:</label>
            <input type="text" id="date" name="date" required minlength="17" maxlength="17" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Note: I tried a few modifications in css and in DOM style with JavaScript, that I can't recall them since they were fails ( visibility and z-index most of the time ) .
I was expecting to combine this two things just with HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript (ES6 Tops) - https://jsfiddle.net/Apryed/gnuebymf/ :

A clickable drop down
A Tool tip with descriptive information

To hide a few things from showing and to describe what should be inserted inside.
Notice how the Drop down gently reveals and hides in comparison to the other fiddle.
Edit: As per request of Bharata - Don't actually know why, since I've seen post like mine... but fine with me.


let ShHi = document.getElementsByClassName("ShowHide1")
for (let i = 0; i < ShHi.length; i++) {
  ShHi[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("show")
    let nextEl = this.nextElementSibling
    nextEl.classList.toggle("active")
    if (nextEl.style.maxHeight) {
      nextEl.style.maxHeight = null
    } else {
      nextEl.style.maxHeight = nextEl.scrollHeight + "px"
    }
  })
}
/* DropDown Part */
.ShowHide1 {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ToolTip1 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

/* ToolTip Part */
.ToolTip2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ToolTip2 > :nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ToolTip2 .ToolTipText2 {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(-5px - 100%));
  transform: translateY(calc(-5px - 100%));
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.ToolTip2 .ToolTipText2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.ToolTip2:hover .ToolTipText2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>DropDown Part</h2>
        <h3 class="ShowHide1"><u>Click Me!</u></h3>
        <div class="ToolTip1">
      <div>
        <label for="x">Some randomtext</label>
              <input id="x" name="x"/>
      </div>
        </div>
    <hr>
    <h2>ToolTip Part</h2>
        <h3>No Need to Click Me!</h3>
        <div class="ToolTip2">
      <div class="ToolTipText2">
        Text to display
      </div>
      <div>
              <label for="x1">Hover over this green area</label>
              <input id="x1" name="x1"/>
      </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>




You have to add your code here and not on Jsfiddle, please!

I think I'm done. Did you mean like this or as snippet?

Your problem is the overflow hidden on your parent element tooltip, think about it, the code is working it is hidden because of that rule on the parent.

So it won't show its content even if overflow is set to visibile? - I think I test it... can't remember.

@Apryed, with a snippet it would be better, but so it is also enough. But now it is to late for me to answer your question ☹️

Well, the fiddle link is the same as the snippet (As told you before). Maybe there's a way to improve the code, I'll be checking for improvements once I'm back home. Don't be harsh on new posters.

@Apryed, very good! Now is your question perfect! I don’t like jsfiddle.

There you go:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .tooltip {
        width: 120px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(-5px - 100%));
        transform: translateY(calc(-5px - 100%));
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: 1s;
      }

      .tooltip::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
      }

      .expand {
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: fit-content;
      }

      .container {
        position: relative;
        width: fit-content;
      }

      .container:hover .tooltip {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }

      .expandable {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        max-height: 0;
        transition: 0.3s ease-out;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .expandable_content {
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tooltip">tooltip</div>
      <div class="expandable">
        <div class="expandable_content">
          <label for="x1">Hover over this green area</label>
          <input id="x1" name="x1" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="expand">Expand 2</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tooltip">tooltip 2</div>
      <div class="expandable">
        <div class="expandable_content">
          <label for="x2">Hover over this green area 2</label>
          <input id="x2" name="x2" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      [...document.querySelectorAll(".expand")].forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let expandable = el.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".expandable");
          if (expandable.style.maxHeight && expandable.style.maxHeight != "0px") {
            expandable.style.maxHeight = 0;
          } else {
            expandable.style.maxHeight = expandable.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


Thank you very much... Is it because of the ToolTipText that the max-height transition won't go as smooth as the one here? - DropDown part.

What have you done? Would you like to add some description, please!  We shouldn't waste our time to understand what you've done here.

What else did you need to understand it? It's a clickable drop down, and that drop down   has a tool tip. Self explanatory. I'll add the snippet, but you could also use the fiddle link I post, it's the same as the snippet.

HI @Bharata, a LOT of minor changes were necessary, I couldn't explain it..

@Apryed that behavior that it seem to pop from the middle apparenctly is caused by the usage of inline-block. I will try to create one example from scratch and share with you

Updated my answer with a cleaner version without inline-block, check it out

Damm... I was thinking it backwards.  ToolTip containing a Wrapper... Will keep it in mind :D
